# Sorting and getting the values of multiple html selects with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm programatically generating select's with integer options (from 0 to 18)
My aim is to filter the results into separate categories of ages like : 
infant  less than 2
children greater than 2 less than 18
Adult greater or equal to 18

```
    $('.passengerAge').filter(function (req1) {

    var valbebe = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) <= 2;
         
    return valbebe;
          
    });
    $('.passengerAge').filter(function (req2) {
    var valadulte = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) >= 18;
         
    return valadulte;
          
    });

    $('.passengerAge').filter(function (req3) {

    var valenfant = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) < 18 && parseInt($(this).val(), 10) > 2 ;
         
    return valenfant;
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select class="passengerAge" id="select_1" name="select_1">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    </select>
```

The code is working, but only displaying the last returned value.
second, i need to display every returned value in hidden and separated text inputs, so i have first to get the values and then push them into inputs.

Any hints ?

Comment: where do you return the result of the filter function to?

Comment: @errand well i will try to push the value into text inputs ex if i have 3 children and 2 adults and zero babies it will be : 
<input type="hidden" name="numAdults" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="numInfants" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="numChildren" value="3">

Comment: so i assume you have more code around this one?

Comment: @errand all i need is in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/d62r26hp/
1st step : generate the selects with ages from 0-18 -> working perfectly 
2nd step : getting the values -> not working :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way you called the .filter() function doesn't work because it gets executed on document ready - even if your count would be correct, it would always return 5 infants (since default value seems to be 0)

i don't understand the way, you allocate the age group variables, like valadulte. either i don't know this shortcut for comparision/allocation statements, or it's just broken. so i did it the long way, using if statements...

**first** you have to bind an event trigger to your count function, to count the values, when you want them to be counted.

```
$('.passengerAge').on("change", function(){
  //put age-group counting code here
});
```

this could be simply on change of any of the select fields, like above or

```
$('.btnConfirm').on("click", function(){
  //put age-group counting code here
});
```

be triggered when clicking the confirmation button

**second** part is the code, to count your age groups.
at the beginning of the operation, we reset the values, to be on the safe side

```
$("input[name='numAdults']").val("0");
$("input[name='numInfants']").val("0");
$("input[name='numChildren']").val("0");
```

then we cycle through each select box and use if statements to compare the selected value. within the if block, you increment the appropriate value...

```
 $('.passengerAge').each(function(){ 

 if($("option:selected", this).attr("value") < 2)
 {
     $("input[name='numInfants']").val( function(i, oldval) {
    return ++oldval;
    });
 }

  if($("option:selected", this).attr("value") > 2 && $("option:selected", this).attr("value") < 18)
 {
  $("input[name='numChildren']").val( function(i, oldval) {
    return ++oldval;
    });
 }

if($("option:selected", this).attr("value") == 18)
 {
  $("input[name='numAdults']").val( function(i, oldval) {
    return ++oldval;
    });
 }
});
```

use your browser inspector to check the hidden fields with your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d62r26hp/1/

Comment: i can't vote need +15 reputation, so thank you kind sir it works perfectly !